# Default value C# class

Tags: c#

I have a function in a controller, and I receive the information for a form. I have this code:

```
public Actionresult functionOne(string a, string b, string c = "foo" )
```

I tried to convert this to a class like

```
public class bar
{
    public string a {get;set;}
    public string b {get;set;}
    public string c {get;set;}
}
```

and receive them as a object

```
 public Actionresult functionOne(bar b)
```

Also I tried to put the defaultvalue in 'c' but is not working, I tried this:

```
public class bar
{
    public string a {get;set;}
    public string b {get;set;}
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("foo")]
    public string c {get;set;}
}
```

Nothing happened with that, I receive it as `null`

also I tried

```
public class bar
{
    public string a {get;set;}
    public string b {get;set;}
    public string c 
    {
        get
        {
            return  c;
        }
        set
        {
            c="foo"; //I also tried with value
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to write this default value?

Comment: Maybe put a default value in the constructor ?

Comment: The `[DefaultValue]` attribute indeed does not do anything; it is meant for designers to be able to determine with what value you initialize a property.

Comment: Hi.
A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

DefaultValueAttribute usefull for reflection when read any of member in reflection is null use this attribute to find or set default value.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are using *C# 6* you can do this:

```
public class Bar {
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; } = "foo";
}
```

Otherwise you can do this:

```
public class Bar {
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    private string _c = "foo";
    public string c
    {
        get
        {
            return _c;
        }
        set
        {
            _c = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

1) Use the object's constructor:

```
public class bar
{
    public bar() 
    {
       c = "foo";
    }

    public string a {get;set;}
    public string b {get;set;}
    public string c {get;set;}
}
```

2) Utilize the new auto property default value.  [Note that this is for C# 6+](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status):

```
public class bar
{

    public string a {get;set;}
    public string b {get;set;}
    public string c {get;set;} = "foo";
}
```

3) Use a backing field

```
public class bar
{
    var _c = "foo";
    public string a {get;set;}
    public string b {get;set;}
    public string c {
       get {return _c;} 
       set {_c = value;}
    }
}
```

4) Use the [Null Coalescing Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) check

```
public class bar
    {
        string _c = null;
        public string a {get;set;}
        public string b {get;set;}
        public string c {
           get {return _c ?? "foo";} 
           set {_c = value;}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried a default constructor which sets the value of C?

```
public class Bar
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    public Bar()
    {
        C = "foo";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign Default value in constructor

```
public class bar
{
    public bar()
    {
        this.c = "foo";
    }

    public string a {get;set;}
    public string b {get;set;}
    public string c {get;set;}
}
```

Whenever `bar` object is created, constructor will be called and `c` will be initialized with "foo".

Later when some other method is called `c` will be updated with its value like

```
public class bar
{
    public bar()
    {
        this.c = "foo";
    }

    public string a {get;set;}
    public string b {get;set;}
    public string c {get;set;}

    public void UpdadateValueofC(string updatedvalueofc)
    {
        this.c = updatedvalueofc;
    }
}
```